# cssのmarginが効いていない

Tags: html, css

#### 問題

指している所にmarginが反映されていない

###目 標
marginを反映させる
news  other-service➡の部分

#### 目標画像

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]
[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

#### 現在

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]
[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

```
HTML
<section>
 <div class=our-service>
  <div class="content1">
    <div class="Our-Service fadeIn_down fadeIn">
      <h1>Our Service</h1>
    </div>
      <li class="fadeIn_up fadeIn">
       <div class="content1-wrp">
        <div class="content1-imgs1">
          <img src="image/educure01.jpg">
        </div>
         <div class="servis-text">
          <img class=img1 src="./image/black.png" alt="">
           <p class=first-text>DXを推進するエンジニア育成</p>
           <p class=second-text>IT事業参入をご検討中の事業者様向けのサービスです。</p>
         </div>
      </div>
    </li>
  </div>
  <div id="content2">
   <li class="fadeIn_up fadeIn">
    <div class="service-text2">
      <img class=img2 src="./image/logo.png" alt="">
      <p class=first-text>未経験から</br>本気でエンジニアへ</p>
      <p class=second-text>「未経験から本気でエンジニア」を目指すプログラミングスクールです。</p>
   　</div>
　  <div class=content-imgs2>
      <img src="./image/techpassion01.jpg" alt="">
    </div>
   </li>
  </div>
  <div id="content3">
   <li class="fadeIn_up fadeIn">
　  <div class=content-imgs3>
      <img src="./image/6c40ac7b707e13491fda6a6b4f02d82d.jpg" alt="">
    </div>
    <div class="service-text3">
      <img class=img3 src="./image/abb886337b510d088a858a59a12bf114.png" alt="">
      <p class=first-text>人生を変える英会話アプリ</p>
      <p class=second-text>登録者25万人！YouTuber講師ジョージ監修！オンライン英会話アプリ！</p>
   　</div>
   </li>
  <div class="other-service fadeIn_right fadeIn">
  <a href="#">Other-service ➡</a>
  </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="our-divsion">
 <li class="fadeIn_down fadeIn">
  <div class="vision-menu">
    <div class="our-vision fadeIn_down fadeIn">
    <h1>our-vision</h1>
    </div>
  </li>
   <div class="vision-title fadeIn_up fadeIn">
    <h3>世界の課題をITで解決して、</br>関わった<strong>世界中の人たちを幸せにする<strong></h3>
   </div>
    <ul class="vision-service">
      <li class="fadeIn_up fadeIn">
        <p class="vision-text1">ITを通じて</br>人々の可能性を広げる</p>
        <p class="vision-text2">イノベーションを起こし新たな価値を創造する</p>
      </li>
      <li class="fadeIn_up fadeIn">
        <p class="vision-text1">世界を代表する</br>自社サービスを作る</br>人々の可能性を広げる</p>
        <p class="vision-text2">世の中にインパクトを与える</p>
      </li>
      <li class="fadeIn_up fadeIn">
        <p class="vision-text1">世界から選ばれる企業へ</p>
        <p class="vision-text2">常に最高のパフォーマンスを発揮します</p>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
 </div>

<div class=news>
 <li class="fadeIn_down fadeIn">
   <div class="news-menu">
    <div class="news fadeIn_down fadeIn">
     <h1>News</h1>
  </li>
</div>
<div class="news-topics">
  <div class="news-topic">
   <div class="news-list fadeIn_up fadeIn">
     <img width="170" height="90" src="/image/prtimes.png">
    <div class="news-text">
     <p>2022-01-14 <a href="#">プレスリリース　メディア<a/> <a href="#">自社サービス</a> </p>
       <a href="#">【プレリリース】DXを促進するリスキング(再教育)サービス</br>「EDUcare(エドゥキュア)」</a>
    </div>
   </div>
   <div class="news-list fadeIn_up fadeIn">
     <img width="170" height="90" src="/image/prtimes.png">
    <div class="news-text">
     <p>2022-10-29 <a href="#">プレスリリース　メディア<a/> <a href="#">自社サービス</a> </p>
     <a href="#">【プレリリース】【プレスリリース】IT人材教育システム「educure」”Cross Education Lab.”
       芝浦工大 新熊亮一教授監修により更にデータドリブンな教育プログラムが提供可能に！</a>
    </div>
   </div>
   <div class="news-list fadeIn_up fadeIn">
     <img width="170" height="90" src="/image/IMG_0218-4-125x125.jpeg">
    <div class="news-text">
     <p>2021-05-01 <a href="#">会社情報<a/> </p>
     <a href="#">本社オフィス移転のお知らせ</a>
    </div>
   </div>
   <div class="news-list fadeIn_up fadeIn">
     <img width="170" height="90" src="/image/prtimes.png">
    <div class="news-text">
     <p>2021-04-01 <a href="#">プレスリリース　メディア<a/> <a href="#">自社サービス</a> </p>
     <a href="#">【プレスリリース】人材派遣の勤怠管理から請求書作成、従業員の給与明細まで
       一元化できる管理システム「kint」をリリース</a>
    </div>
   </div>
   <div class="news-list fadeIn_up fadeIn">
     <img width="170" height="90" src="/image/prtimes.png">
    <div class="news-text">
     <p>2021-03-01 <a href="#">プレスリリース　メディア<a/> <a href="#">自社サービス</a> </p>
     <a href="#">【プレスリリース】未経験からエンジニアになれる、IT人材教育プログラミングスクール「Tech Passion」開講</a>
    </div>
   </div>
   <div class="other-service2 fadeIn_right fadeIn">
     <a href="#">other-service ➡</a>
   </div>
 </div>
</div>

</section>
<html>
```

css

```
#our-service{
    z-index: 9;
}

.content1{
    margin:  auto;
    padding-top: 125px;
}

.content1-wrp{
    display: flex;
}

h1{
     font-size: 28px;
     font-family: 'Noto Sans JP', sans-serif;
     border-top: solid 2px #2da690;
     max-width: 200px;
     margin: 0 auto;
     font-weight: 500px;
     text-decoration: none;
     padding-top: 4px;
     text-align:center;
     white-space: nowrap;
}


.content1-imgs1 img{
 height:665px;
 width: 665px;
 object-fit: contain;
 right: 42vw;
 bottom: -37vw;
}

.servis-text{
    height: 340.5px;
    width: 672px;
    position: absolute;
    background-color: #fff;
    right: 13vh;
    bottom: 20vh;
    opacity: 0.9;
    font-family: 'Noto Sans JP', sans-serif;
}

.service-text2{
    position: absolute;
    background-color: #fff;
    font-family: 'Noto Sans JP', sans-serif;
    opacity: 0.9;
    height: 373px;
    width: 672px;
    margin-left: 15vh;
    z-index: 2;
}

.service-text3{
    height: 340.5px;
    width: 672px;
    position: absolute;
    background-color: #fff;
    right: 13vh;
    bottom: 20vh;
    opacity: 0.9;
    font-family: 'Noto Sans JP', sans-serif;
    z-index: 2;
    bottom: 13vh;
}

.service-text3 img{
    height: 64px;
    width: 76px;
    max-height: 64px;
    max-width: 100%;
    margin-top: 2rem;
}

.img1{
 display: flex;
 height:100px;
 width: 200px;
 object-fit: contain;
 position: relative;
 margin:40px;
 margin-top: 10px;
}

.img2{
    display: flex;
    height:100px;
    width: 200px;
    object-fit: contain;
    position: relative;
    margin:40px;
  margin-top: 10px;
}

.img3{
    display: flex;
    height:100px;
    width: 200px;
    object-fit: contain;
    position: relative;
    margin:40px;
    margin-top: 10px;
}

.first-text{
 font-size: 32px;
 margin: -20px 0 20px 45px;
}

.second-text{
    margin:0 0 20px 45px;
    opacity: 0.5;
}

#content2{
    width: 1120px;
}

#content3{
  line-height: 5rem;
    width: 100%;
}

.content-imgs2 img{
    height: 457px;
    width: 684px;
  max-height: 500px;
    max-width: 100%;
  margin:0 0 0 80vh;
    position: relative;
  bottom:10vh;
    z-index: 1;
}

.content-imgs3 img{
    height: 399px;
    width: 684px;
    max-height: 500px;
    max-width: 100%;
    margin:0 0 0 0vh;
    position: relative;
    bottom:10vh;
    z-index: 1;
}

.other-service {
    text-align: right;
    margin-bottom: 5rem;
    font-weight: bold;
    padding-right: 2rem;
}

.other-service a {
    color: black;
}

.our-divsion{
    padding: 5rem 0 7rem 0;
    background-image: url(./image/bg01.jpg);
    background-size: 100% auto;
}

.vision-service li {
    width: 33.3%;
}

.vision-title h3 {
    font-size: 2.6rem;
    font-weight: 400;
    margin: 0 auto;
    text-align: center;
    margin-bottom: 4rem;
}

.vision-service {
    display: flex;
}


.vision-text1 {
    font-size: 2rem;
    font-weight: 700;
  line-height: 2.5rem;
  color: #2da690;
  margin: 0 0 1.5rem;
    text-align: center;
}

.vision-text2 {
 margin: 0;
 font-size: 1rem;
 line-height: 1.5rem;
 font-weight: 400;
 color: #808080;
 text-align: center;
}

.news-topics{
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding-left: 2.5rem;
    padding-right: 2.5rem;
    width: 100%;
    max-width: calc( 1120px + 2.5rem * 2);
}

.news-list{
    display: flex;
    padding: 1rem 0 1rem 0;
    border-bottom: 1px solid rgba(0,0,0,0.12);
}

.news-list img{
    object-fit: cover;
}

.news-text {
    padding-left: 1rem;
}

.news-text a {
    color: gray;
}

.news-text p a {
    color: black;
}

.news-text p a {
    color:#C0C0C0;
}

.other-service2{
    text-align: right;
    margin-bottom: 5rem;
    font-weight: bold;
    padding-right: 2rem;
}

.other-service2 a {
    color: black;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`.other-service2`には`margin-bottom`しか設定されていないようです。
`margin-top`を設定すれば良いのでは。

Comment: ありがとうございます。
解決いたしました。